# string not in php array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to write an if statement for an array IP's. If the users IP is NOT in the array then proceed. However I think my array set up is incorrect, should I be using in_array for this?

```
$ip_list = array(
    "127.0.0.2",
    "127.0.0.1"
);

if ($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] != $ip_list) {
    // success code
};
```

Comment: *should I be using in_array for this?* Have you tried using it?

Comment: Yes you should use in_array(). Should work, if `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` is a string ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Use **[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)**  to checks if a value exists in an array

```
if (!in_array($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $ip_list)) {
    // success code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use IP's as keys (for performance reasons, depends how many IP's you'll have), and then do a array_key_exists:

```
$ip_list = array(
    "127.0.0.2" => '',
    "127.0.0.1" => ''
);

if (!array_key_exists($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$ip_list)) {
    // success code
};
```

Comment: You're right.  Missed the `=> ''`'s on my small screen.  Sorry

Comment: this is also correct but little lengthy creating key value array!!

Comment: @Saty Yeah, but I think it's a good practice to use keys instead of value. It avoids the next question "Why is in_array slow on my 1,000 values array ?"... If you always use keys, you never have problems... But that's my opinion...

Answer (score 1):

use in_array() function like

```
if(!in_array($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$ip_list)
{...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using `in_array` would be:

```
if (!in_array($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $ip_list)){
//success code
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution shuld be:

```
$ip_list = array(
"127.0.0.2",
"127.0.0.1");
if (!in_array($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $ip_list)) {
// success code
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 : use `in_array()` to find the value in array

```
<?php
$ip_list = array("127.0.0.2","127.0.0.1");
if(in_array($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$ip_list))
{
    echo "REMOTE ADDR is Available";
}
?>
```

Method 2 : use `array_search()`, it will return the key of searched value if exist in `$ip_list`

```
<?php
$ip_list = array("127.0.0.2","127.0.0.1");
$key = array_search($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$ip_list);
if(is_int($key))
{
    echo "REMOTE ADDR is Available";
}
?>
```